# PHP Convention - Assignment in condition

Tags: php, coding-style

I'm been searching what the correct PHP convention is for assignments in conditions.

```
<?php
if(false !== ($var = something())) {
  ...
}

// or

if(($var = something()) !== false) {
  ...
}
```

Usually I'm using the first solution for small methods that I don't want to clutter with too much code, but some of my collegues use it the other way. What would be the right one to use and why?

I know that functionally it doesn't matter at all, I'm just asking this for enlightenment on conventions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"I don't know why people complain about lack of conventions in PHP; there are so many to choose from!"* - It depends on what your convention is.

Comment: The "right" way is to follow whatever the accepted coding convention is among the members of your team, which can obviously change from team to team. Voting to close this as not constructive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it the way the code base does it. Don't be that guy who injects your own preferences into the collective which clash with the norm.